# Can't popBackStack() after screen rotation. Android Navigation Components

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using NavController: `Navigation.findNavController(activity, R.id.statistic_host_fragment)`. And is everything good, until i rotate my device and after that i can't `navigate()` and `popBackStack()`.

**In logs**: 
FragmentNavigator: Ignoring popBackStack() call: FragmentManager has already saved its state AND
FragmentNavigator: Ignoring navigate() call: FragmentManager has already saved its state

When I saw Google Sample they didn't anything about this problem, there is all working fine. So I can't understand that is the problem.

Also when I'm using **MVVM**, I'm saving navController in viewModel, and after **onCreate()** reinit controller in viewModel. It solved navigate() problem after rotation but I still can't popBackStack(). After that I trying use `Navigation.setViewNavController()` but it not work.

```
val destId = currentController.currentDestination?.id

    if (destId != R.id.wikiFragment && destId != R.id.statisticsFragment && destId != R.id.trackerFragment)
        currentController.navigateUp()
```

and in HomeActivity:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (vm.currentController.graph.startDestination == vm.currentController.currentDestination?.id) {
        super.onBackPressed()
    } else {
        vm.currentController.popBackStack()
    }
}
```

and all source : https://github.com/SuperCatDev/OverHub/tree/feature/maps

Comment: How you're poping backstack can you show some code.

Comment: You can probably edit your question. Do not put code in comments.

Comment: Yeah it's a good idea)

Answer (score 3):

Solved the problem by extracting all NavControllers from ViewModel and never keep NavController instance. Only use getter methods when acces needed.

Answer (score 0):

okay, I've been working on this annoying error for few hours and solved it.
The key was overriding onResume!

So make one flag variable like this

```
var completePlayed = false
```

And do whatever you wanna do like rotating,onSomethingListener and inside of that change value like this

```
completePlayed = true
```

And then, override onResume

```
 override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    if(completePlayed){
        navController!!.navigate(R.id.action_chpaterSecondFragment_to_chapterPlayerFragment)
    }else{
        toast("false")
    }

}
```